# Redundant conformance of 'TableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got this error and I don't know how to solve it. Anyone can help me? Basically I want to create table.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {
```

I got this error:

Redundant conformance of 'TableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'
Redundant conformance of 'TableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

I already connect dataSource and delegate in my table view.

Refer to this picture 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7gkb.png)

Help me out please :(

Comment: i already read the answer. it is mean i should remove UITableViewController ? Sorry im still confuse

Comment: check the documentation of `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewController` already conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` so you don't need to specify this again in your class declaration.

Go from

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     // ...
}
```

to

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 conformations in your class. You need to extend only once.

First Posibility:

You conform in the class description AND in the extension. Remove "My Delegate" in the class description.

```
class MyViewController: MyDelegate{
    //class functions here
}

extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
}
```

Second posibility:

You conform in two extensions.

```
extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
}

extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func2()
}
```

Merge them into one extension like:

```
extension MyViewController: MyDelegate{
func1()
func2()
}
```